# Show the button of background activity, on displaying transparent activity

Tags: android-activity, background, transparent

I want to show the button of my background activity while rest of the part in background activity is dim on displaying transparent acitivity. Is there any way to just show a single button from xml layout on displaying the transparent layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is make a view which will cover all the view of your screen but with opacity to  10% only so background view appears dim. Disable the userinteraction in the view. Now you can add the button view over the top of view which you added. By doing this user can only click the button view and nothing else. :) It's kind of hack but it works for me may work for you

Comment: Actually we can make the activity transparent by only keeping intent transparent in manifest file. The method u applied will also work. Thanks